# Is 25ms a typical time for creating a ByteBuddy subclass?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

When creating my proxies, the best times I'm seeing are around 25ms (3.2Ghz processor). I'm attempting to trim off tens of millis from code execution, so wondering if this is typical or I'm doing something wrong?

I'm trying to proxy a Hibernate entity with ByteBuddy, here is the setup:

The hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
    private int version;
    // ... about 20 more annotated fields representing columns
```

The proxy creation:

```
private static ByteBuddy byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy();

// ...

private Device getProxy(long id) {
    Device target = new Device();
    // ... populates the target with necessary information

    Device proxyDevice = byteBuddy
        .subclass(Device.class)
        .method(any()).intercept(to(new CatchAllInteceptor()))               
        .method(isGetter()
            .or(isHashCode())
            .or(isToString())
            .or(isEquals()))
            .intercept(to(target))
        .make() 
        .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded()
        .newInstance();
```

I'm very new to ByteBuddy, so there may very well be something glaringly wrong - such as the ability to reuse some of the above definition for the purposes of speeding up each invocation. This block of code is getting called 1200 times a second, so I'm looking to trim as much fat as possible.

I couldn't make the times quoted in [the docs comparison table](https://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) (885.983
 - 5'408.329 ns) match to my experience - though I note those are quoted as a baseline `Object` subclass timings.

Comment: Creating an entire fresh class, loading it, and instantiating it is unlikely to be cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class loader creation is probably the most expensive part of your measurement. In Hibernate, classes are actually injected into a target class loader what cuts some of the costs. This is also done in the benchmark as it is the default approach of cglib and Javassist to have a proper comparison.

You can use the injection strategy by specifying `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION` as the second argument to the `load` method.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Out of interest, I was seeing the most time spent in `make()`. Tried your suggestion but sadly didn't see a lot of gain.
Thanks heaps for your time, great work on the library!

Comment: I would need to profile the particular generation. Typically, the delegarmtor creation is also costly due to the annotation scanning and would be cached in a real class creation. If you measured runtime, what did you spend most time with within make?